# Web Addin Outlook

Tags: javascript, soap, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

I am developing a new web addin for Outlook using EWS and JavaScript. The scope is to get the current email selected and add it to a new email as attachement. Following the instructions found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726694(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_createattachews -> I have created some functions to do those steps explained in the MSDN documentation. The problem is that I don't get any errors or something that can tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is my Code:

```
 function soapToForwardItemCallback(asyncResult) {
        var parser;
        var xmlDoc;

        if (asyncResult.error != null) {
            app.showNotification("EWS Status", asyncResult.error.message);
        }
        else {
            var response = asyncResult.value;
            if (window.DOMParser) {
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
            }
            else // Older Versions of Internet Explorer
            {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
            }

            // Get the required response, and if it's NoError then all has succeeded, so tell the user.
            // Otherwise, tell them what the problem was. (E.G. Recipient email addresses might have been
            // entered incorrectly --- try it and see for yourself what happens!!)
            var result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("m:ResponseCode")[0].textContent;
            if (result == "NoError") {
                app.showNotification("EWS Status", "Success!");
            }
            else {
                app.showNotification("EWS Status", "The following error code was recieved: " + result);
            }
        }
    }







    function getCurrentEmail() {


             var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
             item_id = item.itemId;

            var getMimeContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                                  '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
                                  'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
                                  'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"' +
                                  'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                             //     '  <soap:Header>' +
                            //  '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
                           //  '  </soap:Header>' +
                                  '<soap:Body>' +
                                    '<m:GetItem>' +
                                //     ' xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
                                //  ' xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
                                        '<m:ItemShape>' +
                                            '<t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>' +
                                               '<t:AdditionalProperties>' +
                                                '<t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:MimeContent" />' +
                                                 '<t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />' +
                                                  '</t:AdditionalProperties>' +
                                                    '</m:ItemShape>' +
                                                        '<m:ItemIds>' +
                                                   '<t:ItemId Id="' + item_id + '"/>' +
                                               '</m:ItemIds>' +
                                           '</m:GetItem>' +
                                      '</soap:Body>' +
                                   '</soap:Envelope>'

            mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(getMimeContent, createMail);


    }

   function createMail(asyncResult) {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var xmlDoc;

                if (asyncResult.error !== null) {
                    app.showNotification("EWS Status", asyncResult.error.message);
                }
                else {
                    var response = asyncResult.value;
                    if (window.DOMParser) {

                        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
                    }
                    else // Older Versions of Internet Explorer
                    {
                        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                        xmlDoc.async = false;
                        xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
                    }



                    var toAddresses = 'alexandru.banica@rodacsoft.ro';

                    var addressesSoap = "";

                    addressesSoap += "<t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>" + toAddresses + "</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox>";

                    var soapToCreateNewEmail = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                                               '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'+
                                               'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"'+
                                               'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"'+
                                               ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                                               '     <soap:Header>'+
                                               '     <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />'+
                                               '     </soap:Header>'+
                                               '     <soap:Body>'+
                                               '     <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">'+
                                               '     <m:Items>'+
                                               '     <t:Message>'+
                                               '     <t:Subject>Message with Item Attachment (MimeContent)</t:Subject>'+
                                               '     <t:Body BodyType="HTML">The attachmen</t:Body>'+
                                               '     <t:ToRecipients>'+ addressesSoap
                                               +
                                               ' </t:ToRecipients>'+
                                               ' </t:Message>'+
                                               ' </m:Items>'+
                                               ' </m:CreateItem>'+
                                               ' </soap:Body>'+
                                               ' </soap:Envelope>'

                    mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapToCreateNewEmail,soapToGetItemDataCallback);

                }
 }


 function createAttachement(asyncResult) {

     var parser = new DOMParser();
     var xmlDoc;

     if (asyncResult.error !== null) {
         app.showNotification("EWS Status", asyncResult.error.message);
     }
     else {
         var response = asyncResult.value;
         if (window.DOMParser) {

             xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
         }
         else // Older Versions of Internet Explorer
         {
             xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
             xmlDoc.async = false;
             xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
         }

         var mimeTag = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("t:MimeContent")[0].innerText;

         var soapToCreateAttachement = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                                        ' <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'+
                                       '  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"'+
                                       '  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"'+
                                        ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                                                  '   <soap:Header>'+
                                                    '     <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />'+
                                                     '        </soap:Header>'+
                                                      '           <soap:Body>'+
                                                         '             <m:CreateAttachment>'+
                                                         '             <m:ParentItemId Id="'+item_id+'" />'+
                                                         '             <m:Attachments>'+
                                                         '             <t:ItemAttachment>'+
                                                          '            <t:Name>Play tennis?</t:Name>'+
                                                         '             <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>'+
                                                          '           <t:Message>'+
                                                         '           <t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">'+ mimeTag +'</t:MimeContent>'+
                                                         '            </t:Message>'+
                                                         '        </t:ItemAttachment>'+
                                                         '       </m:Attachments>'+
                                                         '      </m:CreateAttachment>'+
                                                         '     </soap:Body>'+
                                                         '    </soap:Envelope>'


         mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapToCreateAttachement,sendEmailAsAttachement);
     }
 }

 function sendEmailAsAttachement(asyncResult) {

     var parser = new DOMParser();
     var xmlDoc;

     if (asyncResult.error !== null) {
         app.showNotification("EWS Status", asyncResult.error.message);
     }
     else {
         var response = asyncResult.value;
         if (window.DOMParser) {

             xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
         }
         else // Older Versions of Internet Explorer
         {
             xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
             xmlDoc.async = false;
             xmlDoc.loadXML(response);
         }

         var changeKey = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("t:ItemId")[0].getAttribute("ChangeKey");

         var soapToSendEmailAttachment = ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                                        ' <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
                                        ' xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
                                        '   xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"' +
                                        '   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                                        '    <soap:Header>' +
                                        '    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />' +
                                        '            </soap:Header>' +
                                        '            <soap:Body>' +
                                        '            <m:SendItem SaveItemToFolder="true">' +
                                        '            <m:ItemIds>' +
                                        '                <t:ItemId Id="'+ item_id +'"' +
                                        '                    ChangeKey="'+ changeKey +'" />' +
                                        '                    </m:ItemIds>' +
                                        '                <m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
                                        '             <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" />' +
                                        '        </m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
                                        '    </m:SendItem>' +
                                        '  </soap:Body>' +
                                        '  </soap:Envelope>'

         mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapToSendEmailAttachment, soapToForwardItemCallback);
     }
 }
```

The first function called on button click is getCurrentEmail(). I am not sure if I can do the SOAP calls like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please tell me if you need additional information. Thank you!

Comment: Are you expecting someone should create a project, add your code into it, debug it and tell you what's wrong with your code? I believe you should come up with particular question, for example "m:CreateItem request to EWS return the following error ... what's wrong with my request?" Somebody would be willing to help.

Comment: I am not geting any errors, that's one of the problems! If I did... be sure that I would know what to ask. And thank you for your warm advice on how to post a problem...

Comment: I have edit my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I am not sure if I can do the SOAP calls like that.

The following resource describes [EWS operations that add-ins support](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/web-services?product=outlook#ews-operations-that-add-ins-support). "m:CreateAttachment" is not one of them; probably you should start from there.

EDIT:

I don't understand how comes you don't get any errors. Are you debugging? Can you hit break point? Well this is all weird.
Now let me tell you what I've done and what issues with your code I noticed ...

1. I created the simple project and added your code. I called "getCurrentEmail()" function and work just with this function. I didn't verify any other function, because I believe you should do this on your own.
2. Javascript errors: If you use "strict" JS mode (and you should!) the function has "item_id" variable which is not defined as "var". You should make it local by using "var" keyword. Next when you call "mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync" the "mailbox" variable is undefined as well. you should call it as "Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync".
3. EWS request is not properly formed at all. I don't know, may be you played with it, but the example EWS XML from the resource you have provided is different than you are creating by inserting message Id. When I fixed JS errors (look at the point 2 above) and send EWS request it returned starts "Error" and proper description that request is misformed. I have changed the request to match the request provided in example and it returns "success" and information you have requested, as of subject and MIME content.

I will share my code just for the function you have asked and the rest try to do on your own. Here you go ...

```js
      function _wrapSoapEnvelope(payload) {
            var result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
                'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" ' +
                'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
            '<soap:Header>' +
            '<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />' +
            '</soap:Header>' +
            '<soap:Body>' + payload + '</soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>';
            return result;
        };

        function getCurrentEmail() {
            var item = Office.context.mailbox.item,
            item_id = item.itemId;
            var getMimeContent = '<m:GetItem>' +
                                  '<m:ItemShape>' +
                                    '<t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>' +
                                    '<t:AdditionalProperties>' +
                                      '<t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:MimeContent" />' +
                                      '<t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />' +
                                    '</t:AdditionalProperties>' +
                                  '</m:ItemShape>' +
                                  '<m:ItemIds>' +
                                    '<t:ItemId Id="' + item_id + '"/>' +
                                  '</m:ItemIds>' +
                                  '</m:GetItem>'

            Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(_wrapSoapEnvelope(getMimeContent), createMail);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ivanov, thank you for your time in doing this. I posted only a portion of my code (the variables were declared above the first function... Anyhow long story short, I did it. Seems like I need to write all the request like you did, and they actually work after I solved some other issues coming from the callback functions. Thank you! It's a new topic for me and I was spending my energy on MSDN documentation... Have a nice weekend.